# How to make a robust scheduled event?

Tags: android

I want my application to trigger an event at a given time. At the moment I'm using AlarmManager. But this will be lost if the users phone is restarted, or the user uses a task killer or ends the application with the android task manager.

So what is the best way to do this. Should I just use an alarm and have it repeatedly set in a service so when it is deleted it come right back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awake alarm service on boot completed so that all the task will be re scheduled after reboot. You can store alarm id and details in database.

Comment: Does this protect against restarts?

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill for what you need, but check out CommonWare's WakefulIntentService:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Even if you don't want to fire up an entire IntentService when your alarm is triggered, his code should give you some idea of how you can persist your alarms across device reboots.

Comment: That's great. I'll have a good look and see if I can figure out how to use it. Thank you.